# Android tabhost opening in blank screen

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, android-activity

I use tabhost in my project

now i have the following problem when i click on Tab 1 
it starts an new acivity of Tab 1 thats correct and it loads my listview
also perfect but when i click on listview item it should start also a new activity 
but it opens in a blank screen and not in the tabhost/framelayout

here is an example of my code i hope you can advise me thank you very much

Listview Activity / Tab 1

```
[Activity(Label = "Pagina")]
public class Paginas : Activity
{
    ListView listView;
    CMS.APPS CMS = new CMS.APPS();
    List<CMS.Pages> ListPages;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        Core.Context = this;

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Paginas);
        ListPages = CMS.GetPagesAndroid(Core.AdministratieID, null, Core.UserID, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null).ToList();

        listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListViewPaginas);
        listView.Adapter = new PagesAdapter(this, ListPages);
        listView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;
        listView.ItemClick += OnListItemClick;
    }

    protected void OnListItemClick(object sender, Android.Widget.AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var listView = sender as ListView;
        var t = ListPages[e.Position];
        var CMSPage = new Intent(this, typeof(Handler));
        CMSPage.PutExtra("PAG_ID", t.PAG_ID.ToString());
        StartActivity(CMSPage);
        //Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, t.PAG_TITLE, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}
```

what i do right now is start a new activity CMSPage typeof Handler
and it giefs me a blank screen instead of open it in place of Pagina's / Tab 1

EDIT: Tabhost code on Homescreen:

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Homescreen);
        Core.Context = this;

        CreateTab(typeof(Paginas), "Pagina's", "Pagina's", Resource.Drawable._Pagina);
        CreateTab(typeof(Profiel), "Profiel", "Profiel", Resource.Drawable._Profiel);

    }

    private void CreateTab(Type activityType, string tag, string label, int? drawableId = null)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, activityType);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        var spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec(tag);

        if (drawableId > 0)
        {
            var drawableIcon = Resources.GetDrawable(drawableId.Value);
            spec.SetIndicator(label, drawableIcon);
        }
        else
        {
            spec.SetIndicator(label, null);
        }

        spec.SetContent(intent);
        TabHost.AddTab(spec);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough example of what I'm pretty sure will work (i.e. not tested, but I do something similar in my own code).

In your Activity that exists inside the TabActivity

```
var parent = this.Parent as TabContainer;
if (parent != null)
{
    parent.ChangeToTab(tabId);
}
```

In the TabActivity:

```
    public void ChangeToTab(int tabId)
    {
        TabHost.CurrentTab = tabId;
    }
```

When you're creating the TabHost, it needs to be loaded with a tab for the one you want to change to.

Comment: Just to note, when I originally posted this, ChangeToTab was private, but it has to be public (or maybe another less public modifier if you want to test that!)

Comment: Its not what i meant dave when click on tab x it opens an activity refferenced to this tab but that has a list view with onitemclick and that event needs to open in the window where the listview is showing if i do with setcontent view than my listview wont reload